# If $x$ is rational then $\,x+\frac{1}x \,$ is an integer $\iff x = \pm 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $X+\dfrac{1}{X}$ is not an integer number for any rational $X$ and $X \neq 1, X \neq -1$

I think we can substitue $X=\dfrac{P}{Q}$ but I don't know if I can now assume that $\gcd(P,Q)=1$

Comment: If $(P,Q)=D$ set $$\frac Pp=\frac Qq=D$$

Comment: If $P$ and $Q$ have a common divisor $D$, just note that $$X = \frac{P/D}{Q/D}$$

Comment: Yes, if $x$ is rational, we let $x=\frac{a}{b}$, where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers. The proof that this forces $\frac{a}{b}=\pm 1$ should then go smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x + \frac{1}{x} = n =>x^2-nx+1=0$$
The equation $x^2-nx+1=0$ has rational root $=> \delta =n^2-4=k^2$, where $ k$ is integer.
$=>n^2-k^2=4=>(n+k)(n-k)=4=>n+k=+-2$ and  $ n-k=+-2$ $=> n=+-2 => x=+-1$ false!

Comment: The argument has a big gap. Why can you assume that $k$ is an integer? That crucial inference requires justification.

Comment: It is known that if $p$ is a integer and $\sqrt{p} is rational when \sqrt{p} is integer. For additional arguments see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597069/a-b-in-n-a-sqrta22b1-sqrtb22a1-in-bbb-n-to-show-that-a

Comment: Exactly! If that powerful property is used in your proof then it is *essential* to explicitly mention that. Otherwise a reader cannot determine how that crucial inference was made (which is the only difficult part of the proof). In particular, with nothing said, one cannot determine if the inference was made *rigorously.* Beginning students may not be aware of this subtlety, so it is essential to make it clear.

Answer (score 12):

**Hint** $\ n = x+1/x  \Rightarrow x^2\!-nx+1 = 0\,$ so $\,x\,$ is an integer dividing $1$, by the [Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242).